# How to output downsampling bus in single stream on fpga? (verilog)

Tags: fpga, verilog, flipflop, delay

Im working on a block which implements downsampling.

In general it not hard at all to do simple downsampling, all I need is the factor which I should downsample by, and the data input, Im just using counter and delete all the samples except every n'th sample.

here is my code:

```
`include "config.v"

module downsample (
    input                           clk,        // system clock
    input                           rst_n,      // Asynchronous reset active low

    input                           div,        // input valid
    input       [`CRD_WIDTH-1:0]    din,        // data input
    input       [7-1:0]             factor,     // downsample factor

    output reg                      dov,        // downsample output valid
    output reg  [`CRD_WIDTH-1:0]    dout        // downsample data out
);

    reg [7-1:0] cnt;

    initial begin
        cnt  = 7'h01;
        dov  = 1'b0;
        dout = `CRD_WIDTH'b0;
    end

    always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin : downsampling_logic
        if (~rst_n) begin
            dout    <= `CRD_WIDTH'b0;
            dov     <= 1'b0;
            cnt     <= 7'h01;
        end else begin
            if (div) begin
                cnt     <= cnt + 1'b1;
                dout    <= `CRD_WIDTH'b0;
                dov     <= 1'b0;
                if (cnt == factor) begin
                    cnt     <= 7'h01;
                end
                if (cnt == 7'h01) begin
                    dout    <= din;
                    dov     <= 1'b1;
                    cnt     <= 7'h02;
                end
            end else begin
                dout    <= `CRD_WIDTH'b0;
                dov     <= 1'b0;
                cnt     <= 7'h01;
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```

and the output from the block looks like this:

[image]

In this example the factor=4, and everything work as expected.
So what is my problem?

I want the output to be in single stream, I dont want the 'dov' flag to behave like a clock once up and once down.. once the data is ready I want all the data to out continuously.
I prefer not to use FIFO for it.

Thanks

Comment: Proper down sampling involves more than just throwing away samples because you'll create aliasing.

Comment: yea I know.. I need to filter it as well. but thats will be later.. lets assume I just need to downsample, any idea how to output it countinusly? Im thinking abouy delay the input but than what?

Comment: *but thats will be later* - You filter before down sampling.

Comment: you suggesting FIR filter?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything other than down sampling can only (properly) be done when higher frequency artefacts are removed prior to rate reduction.

Comment: ok thanks for the comment. ill maybe add later a block for this.  for now I just asking individual question, that not has to do anything with the concept of downsampling, but when I have output like I show in the question, how can I arrange the output better for continuously output?

Comment: My VHDL's a bit rusty, but looks like you need a if dov then dwns_out<=dwns_in to infer a d_latch which holds the dwns_out data, not sure whether you also need an else dwns_out<=dwns_out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set `dout` to 0 and it will retain its previous value.

Answer (score 3):

> I dont want the 'dov' flag to behave like a clock once up and once down.

Yes, you do.
You need a data valid flag and your 'dov' is just what you need. You can then use that as enable in the following stages of your design. The only issue is that at the moment it is out of phase with your data: shift it back one clock cycle.

> once the data is ready I want all the data to out continuously.

You can't and honestly you don't want to. 
You are discarding X out of Y samples thus your data is no longer continuous. There is nothing wrong with having gaps.

Why do I go against your wishes?
The only way to get what you want is to re-clock the data into a new, slower clock domain. For that you will need to **make** that slower clock. That is most difficult and very error prone. Even more so if it is programmable. We had users twice this week who made a slower clock and both had major problems in the implementation (The simulation was all fine, the FPGA did not work!).

A good, simple design has one clock and one clock only. If your data is not continuous, just use an enable.
*You should avoid multiple clock domains like the plague* and definitely not generate them yourself if there is an alternative.

Comment: thanks for the comment.. I think I go with your approach. the comment above you does answer my question, but in second though I dont want to do it..

Comment: I realized I need to do something else.. I need output block start  which indicated when the output starts to be valid, and output block end which indicated when the block ends and thats all, using the 3 flags (obs, obe and dov) I can use this data in the next block.  Thanks.